# rsync exclude file what given from a find command

Tags: lubuntu, backup, rsync

OS=lubuntu 20.04.
I will upgrade to 22.04 (is not the question)
I want to backup my $HOME, but there are some files that belongs not to my user

Is it possible to give rsync the output from find and let him exclude  that?

My lack on english:

```
find $HOME -not -user $USER
/home/alex/initrd.img-5.3.0-53-generic
/home/alex/backup/restricted.pref
skip
```

Can I give it somehow in this form to rsync? Like from a file?

```
rsync someoption --exclude /path/to my exclude file
```

Not I know how to exclude files and folders but I'm a bit lazzy to change my backup-skript for that if it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in two steps, by redirecting the output of `find` to a file:

```
find $HOME -not -user $USER > myExcludeFiles

rsync someoption --exclude-from=myExcludeFiles
```

From `man rsync`:

```
--exclude-from=FILE     read exclude patterns from FILE
```

Use the full path name to `myExcludeFiles` when running from `cron`.

Comment: thank's. could adapt to my situation.

Comment: You *could* do it in a single step I think - with `--exclude-from=-` to read the list of patterns from standard input - something like `find "$HOME" -not -user "$USER" -print0 | rsync someotption -0 -exclude-from=- ...`

Comment: @steeldriver I agree that you could, and +1 for pointing that out, but I didn't feel like testing this, and doing it in two commands should be less error-prone.

Comment: my skript is running as systemd --user service `rsync -aAXEPos --ignore-existing --progress --verbose \   --exclude-from=exclude-rsync-bereinigt /home/alex/ /media/alex/bionic-home/alex/ `