# How to copy ONLY large files?

Tags: command-line, usb, files

I'm backing up (manually) a computer on some usb keys. I got several splicing errors, probably because the usb keys were formatted as fat32. These errors seem to occur on large files, such as database backups.

I found how to list them :

```
sudo find / -size +1G -ls > LargeFiles.txt
```

And I found how to format a usb key in ext4, so that it will accept large files :

```
sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/sdc1
```

But I didn' find a way to say "Copy only the files larger than (whatever the fat32 limit is) to /media/usb".

It would be nice to have all the database backups on the same usb key.

Please advise.

Comment: you can use rsync. it has an option `--include-from=FILE` I needed it the other way around. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384582/rsync-exclude-file-what-given-from-a-find-command